# magmi - Directory permissions not compatible with Mass Importer operations

Tags: magmi

I am getting erros as below in magmi page.

[image]

what permission we need to give to get solution ? or is there any other problem causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least 755 recursively on each listed directory.

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg